# how to convert data in a log file to ASCII string by Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I got some log files from a search engine. The following is supposed to be country names but I failed to converted it to ASCII in Python. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Data: 505a44facaa3e758845f6e101f4e21f9d99acf63
```

Code:

```
ascii_string = str(base64.b16decode(hex_data))[2:-1]
```

Error: `Non-base16 digit found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decode the hex from the Data string:

```
s = "Data: 505a44facaa3e758845f6e101f4e21f9d99acf63"
print( s.split()[1].decode("hex")
```

For python3 use unhexlify:

```
print(binascii.unhexlify(s.split()[1]))
```

But neither will return a country name.

Your string is actually `"GB"` sha1 hashed.

```
In [9]: import sha

In [10]: sha.new("GB").hexdigest()
Out[10]: '505a44facaa3e758845f6e101f4e21f9d99acf63'
```

Comment: Finding GB... that was well done! I wonder if that is a coincidence.

Comment: @mhawke, more rainbow table than coincidence!

Comment: Still a good find. It would be a bit odd though, to hash the country name in a log file. I suppose that the OP will confirm eventually.

Comment: Thanks a lot! No idea of the reason of hash. It seems every field got hashed. It is a log file from a  RTB ad exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `505a44facaa3e758845f6e101f4e21f9d99acf63` represents an encoded country? It looks suspiciously like the hex digest of a SHA1 hash.

`hex_data` implies that the data is hex encoded. It can be decoded like this:

```
>>> hex_data = '505a44facaa3e758845f6e101f4e21f9d99acf63'
>>> hex_data.decode('hex')
'PZD\xfa\xca\xa3\xe7X\x84_n\x10\x1fN!\xf9\xd9\x9a\xcfc'
```

Where to go from there is anyone's guess.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you just need to convert `hex_data` to upper case:

```
ascii_string = str(base64.b16decode(hex_data.upper()))[2:-1]
```